# Spring.NET AOP logging optional parameter issue

Tags: asp.net-mvc, spring-aop, spring.net

I'm using the setup described in this SO answer: [Unobtrusive AOP with Spring.Net](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9115510/1170932) and source based on [q9114762_aop_on_mvc_controllers on GitHub](https://github.com/serra/stackoverflow/tree/master/spring-questions/q9114762_aop_on_mvc_controllers) to get AOP logging for my controllers.

All is great except when a controller method with optional parameters *is invoked without the optional parameter*.

My test methods:

```
using System.Web.Mvc;

public class OrderController : Controller
{
   [SetMethodInfoAsMessage]
   virtual public ActionResult Test1()
   {
       return null;
   }

    [SetMethodInfoAsMessage]
    virtual public ActionResult Test2(int someParam = 0)
    {
        return null;
    }

    [SetMethodInfoAsMessage]
    virtual public ActionResult Test3(int? someParam = 0)
    {
        return null;
    }

    [SetMethodInfoAsMessage]
    virtual public ActionResult Test4(int someParam)
    {
        return null;
    }
}
```

and here's the corresponding behaviour when GETting these methods from a browser:

1. `http://localhost:62376/Order/Test1` - 200 OK
2. `http://localhost:62376/Order/Test2` - `500 Internal Server Error. Server Error in '/' Application. The parameters dictionary contains an invalid entry for parameter 'someParam' for method 'System.Web.Mvc.ActionResult Test2(Int32)' in 'InheritanceAopProxy_7b93ae81d25d46529bebc7ed00ebc409'. The dictionary contains a value of type 'System.Reflection.Missing', but the parameter requires a value of type 'System.Int32'. Parameter name: parameters`
3. `http://localhost:62376/Order/Test2?someParam=15` - 200 OK
4. `http://localhost:62376/Order/Test3` - `500 Internal Server Error. Server Error in '/' Application. The parameters dictionary contains an invalid entry for parameter 'someParam' for method 'System.Web.Mvc.ActionResult Test3(System.Nullable1[System.Int32])' in 'InheritanceAopProxy_7b93ae81d25d46529bebc7ed00ebc409'. The dictionary contains a value of type 'System.Reflection.Missing', but the parameter requires a value of type 'System.Nullable1[System.Int32]'. Parameter name: parameters`
5. `http://localhost:62376/Order/Test3?someParam=15` - 200 OK
6. `http://localhost:62376/Order/Test4` - `500 Internal Server Error. Server Error in '/' Application. The parameters dictionary contains a null entry for parameter 'someParam' of non-nullable type 'System.Int32' for method 'System.Web.Mvc.ActionResult Test4(Int32)' in 'InheritanceAopProxy_7b93ae81d25d46529bebc7ed00ebc409'. An optional parameter must be a reference type, a nullable type, or be declared as an optional parameter. Parameter name: parameters`

The last test (6.) makes sense since someParam is mandatory. But we can see from 2. and 4. that not supplying an optional parameter results in a 500. Another thing to note is the error text from 4. - *An optional parameter must be a reference type, a nullable type, or be declared as an optional parameter.* So according to this, 4. should work, right? (since Test3's optional parameter is nullable).

Has anyone else experienced this?  Anyone have any suggestions as to a workaround (other than manually adding logging statements to the methods) ?

This is using Spring.Aop 1.3.2, Spring.Core 1.3.2, Spring.Web. 1.3.2 and Spring.Web.Mvc3 1.3.2.

EDIT: as requested, here's the advice. It simply logs out args except for passwords (we don't want those logged):

```
public class SetMethodInfoAsMessageAdvice : IMethodBeforeAdvice //, IThrowsAdvice
{
    private static readonly PELogger log = Log4NetHelper.GetLogger(typeof(SetMethodInfoAsMessageAdvice));

    public void Before(MethodInfo m, object[] args, object target)
    {
        ILog logger = LogManager.GetLogger(m.DeclaringType);

        string dump = args.ToJson();
        if (dump.Contains("password", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
            dump = "<password hidden>";

        logger.Info(m.Name + "(" + dump + ")");
   }
}
```

Comment: Can we see the advice for your SetMethodInfoAsMessage attribute? This smells like it comes either from that or Spring's proxy.